# how to add a CSS class inside a JavaScript setup code?

Tags: javascript, css, class

I need JavaScript help.

I have this slider script :

```
stepcarousel.setup({
    galleryid: 'mygallery', //id of carousel DIV
    beltclass: 'belt', //class of inner "belt" DIV containing all the panel DIVs
    panelclass: 'panel', //class of panel DIVs each holding content
    autostep: {
        enable:true, 
        moveby:1, 
        pause:3000
    },
    panelbehavior: {
        speed:500, 
        wraparound:false, 
        wrapbehavior:'slide', 
        persist:true
    },
    defaultbuttons: {
        enable: true, 
        moveby: 1, 
        leftnav: ['arl.png', -5, 80], 
        rightnav: ['arr.png', -20, 80]
    },
    statusvars: ['statusA', 'statusB', 'statusC'], //register 3 variables that contain current panel (start), current panel (last), and total panels
    contenttype: ['inline'] //content setting ['inline'] or ['ajax', 'path_to_external_file']
})
```

And I actually want `defaultbuttons` to have a class ( `class="defaultbuttons"` for example )
 because I don't have access to the HTML since the script is 'echoing' it I guess on load ...
I get this :

```
<img src="arl.png" 
     title="Back 1 panels" 
     style="z-index: 50; 
            position: absolute; 
            left: 3px; 
            top: 88px; 
            cursor: pointer; 
            opacity: 1;"
>
```

and i want to add a simple class to do further styling.
Thank You so much for your assistance ;)

Comment: what plugin do you use?

Comment: hello. what you mean by plugin ? you want the entire JS code or what ? thanks!

Comment: the code you've posted, where it comes from? is this the plugin you have downloaded and you are using? http://plugins.jquery.com/oneStepCarousel/ if not, please provide a name/link, thanks

Comment: This `stepcarousel` object is echoing your images. So, we need to know, is there any option to add class for it.

Comment: ok, here is the entire code:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/stepcarousel.js
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/stepcarousel.htm

Comment: If you read the documentation in that page, you can see that you can't add a class to the nav arrows. Check the license of that plugin, and if you can, edit the js code that appends the html for the arrows and hardcode your class name there.

Comment: thanks a lot i figured out a way to add in Js file. thanks for the hint ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it. i should have looked deep into the js.. i could locate this

```
<img src="'+config.defaultbuttons.leftnav[0]+'">
```

then, problem solved! 
Thank You All for your hints and help ;)